# How to get the current context in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using a bottom navigation bar. On a certain Event trigger I need to show some alert on the current screen.

This is how I have implemented the bottom navigation bar. I have four tabs.
Here, I need to change the icon of the 4th tab when `_isHomeDetected` is true and when the user clicks on the icon, i.e on index 3 I have to show an alert message irrespective of which tab the user is in. How do I do this?

```
class LandingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static Widget bottomNavigationBar;
  ..
}

class _LandingScreenState extends State<LandingScreen> {
  ...
  StreamSubscription<String> _subscription;
  bool _isHomeDetected = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    ...
    _subscription = server.messages.listen(onData, onError: onError);
  }
  onData(message) {
    setState(() {
      _isHomeDetected = json.decode(message)["isHomeBeacon"];
    });
  }
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LandingScreen.bottomNavigationBar = new BottomNavigationBar(
        ....
    );
    return new Scaffold(
      body: _currentPage,
      bottomNavigationBar: LandingScreen.bottomNavigationBar,
    );
  }

  _navigateToScreens(int currentIndex) {
    List screens = [
      ..
    ];
    setState((){

      if (!_isHomeDetected || currentIndex != 3){
        _currentPage = screens[currentIndex];
      } else {
        Utils.showCupertinoAlert(
            context: context, content: "You wanna log out???");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get where the problem is. I can't find most things in your code that you mention in the text. Where exactly are you not able to reference `context`?

Comment: Since your code to show Alert Dialog is with in the build method itself, you can always access it.

Answer (score 6):

Declare a **global key**

```
final globalNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

then assign this global key to your **MaterialApp**

```
return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          navigatorKey: globalNavigatorKey,
          theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue,),
          home: MyHomePage(),
);
```

then wherever you want just call example : -

```
const snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'));

ScaffoldMessenger.of(globalNavigatorKey.currentContext).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Answer (score 3):

Within the build method of any stateful widget you'll be able to get the build context. If you can't do this, the below sample from flutter team uses a `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>` to hace access to show snackBar alert.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/cupertino/cupertino_alert_demo.dart

Comment: Anywhere within the State class actually. `State` has a `context` member/getter

Comment: As the link is broken by now, does anyone has this example?

Comment: @progNewbie This link worked for me: [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f3b426a5fc099c705263182bfdc951e3eae89c04/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/cupertino/cupertino_alert_demo.dart) ... although I'm not sure that it demonstrates the use of GlobalKey anymore!

Comment: Thank you for the answer ... it solved my problem:

In case someone is looking for the details:

```
// 1
GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> _scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey();

// 2
MaterialApp(
   scaffoldMessengerKey: _scaffoldMessengerKey,
)

// 3
_scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(....)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on the answer given by @Ron Geo:

Please note that this answer should be considered if your situation is one where:
The widget you are trying to call `showSnackBar` from isn't a child of `MaterialApp`.

As an example, this is the case below:

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp();
  }
}
```

Now, if you want `App` widget to show a snackbar, the following can be done:

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // 1
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> _scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( 
      // 2
      scaffoldMessengerKey: _scaffoldMessengerKey,
    );
  }

  // 3
  void showSnackBar() {
     _scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(....);
  }
}
```

---

Just to re-iterate this solution is NOT required in most cases where the widget you are calling showSnackBar from is already a child of MaterialApp ... in that case the following code will simply work:

```dart
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  void showSnackBar() {
     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(....);
  }
}
```